# How do I use PHP to display one html page or another?

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I wanted to use PHP and the if statement, and I wanted to do

```
if ($variable){
display html page1
}
else {
display html page2
}
```

How do I do this? An please note, that I do not want to redirect the user to a different page.

--EDIT--
I would have no problem doing that with one of them, but the other file, it would be too much of a hassle to do that.

--EDIT--
Here is the coding so far:

```
<?PHP
include 'uc.php';
if ($UCdisplay) {
    include("under_construction.php");
}
else {
    include("index.html");
}
?>
```

My problem is that it would be really complicated and confusing if I were to have to create an html page for every php page, so I need some way to show the full html page instead of using include("index.html")

Answer (score 7):

```
if ($variable){
  include("file1.html");
}
else {
  include("file2.html");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to have your HTML in two separate files and use [include()](http://php.net/include):

```
if ($variable) {
    include('page1.html');
}
else {
    include('page2.html');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

using the ternary operator:

```
 include(($variable ? 'page1' : 'page2').'.html');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid creating "an html page for every php page", then you could do something like this, with the "real" content directly inside the PHP page.

```
<?PHP
include 'uc.php';
if ($UCdisplay) {
    include("under_construction.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<html>

<!-- Your real content goes here -->

</html>
```

The idea is this: If `$UCdisplay` is true, then your under construction page is shown, and execution stops at `exit;` - nothing else is shown.  Otherwise, program flow "falls through" and the rest of the page is output.  You'll have one PHP file for each page of content.

You could side-step this issue by moving the code that checks `$UCdisplay` directly into uc.php; this would prevent you from having to write that same if statement at the top of every file.  The trick is to have the code `exit` after you include the construction page.

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking:
See the `readfile();` function in php. It reads and prints a file all in one function.

**Definition**

```
int readfile ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context ]] )
```

Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.